# onSuccess(contacts) is not fired

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

[image]

Hi all I have been working to display the contacts in my phone with the following code but onSuccess(contacts) is not fired alert(contacts.length) is not working while alert("k") works.
can anyone please help me thank you in advance

Comment: I have also added the error function, even that's not fired

Answer (score 0):

have you set all the permission to work with the contacts?

Maybe you should create also the onError function, to see if the event is called and get the error

Comment: Have you update your project. This issue is know for cordova 2.2.0

Comment: I am using cordova-2.3.0 @dpfauwadel